# Local Area Connection doesn't exist

Tags: windows-10

I've been trying to find a solution for this for some time now. I'm connected to the internet via Wi-Fi and I'm trying to share that connection to a Raspberry pi via ethernet cable.

The problem is that I can't find a Local Area Connection anywhere. I think the adapter may be missing but I don't know what to search for to get it. My machine is an Asus K53E.

In "Network Connections" are two ethernet connections, Wi-Fi connection and 3 other connections belonging to my VMs (VMware and VBox). Nothing local.

Any ideas on how to get a Local Area Connection running? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You list "two ethernet connections, Wi-Fi connection and 3 other connections belonging to my VMs", six altogether. One of the Ethernet connections will be your hardware and you set this interface in the **Sharing** tab of the WiFi adapter properties. You don't need a **Local Area Connection** - none of my W10 machines has it, but there is no problem with networking on either the Internet or Intranet.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that may have been the case, but pinging the broadcast address resulted in 100% packet loss and I thought the LAN may have been the issue. I guess the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about pinging anything local: try pinging an internet address, such as `www.google.com`. You said it was the internet you wanted to share, not the local network.

Answer (score 0):

You already have two of those – they're just labelled "Ethernet".